# Excel Return "TRUE" IF Cell 1 = Cell 2 OR IF Cell 2 ISBLANK, Else "FALSE"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am attempting to create a formula that will return "TRUE" if cell `A1 = B2`, OR return "TRUE" if cell B2 `ISBLANK`.

seems easy to find with research, but I am struggling. from what I can find in is a bit confusing, and I have been trying different approaches for a while and am stuck.

I've Tried

```
=IF(OR(A1 = B2,A1 = ISBLANK(B2),"TRUE","FALSE"))

=IF(OR(ISBLANK(B2)),OR(A1 =B2)"TRUE","FALSE")
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it will return `TRUE`,`FALSE`:

```
=OR(B2="",A1=B2)
```

Comment: Thanks Scott - I was over complicating my thinking for sure.  :)